# Constant random variables

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a constant random variable with value $x_{0}$. Show that $E(X) = x_{0}$.

I have tried:

$$E(X) = \sum^{\infty}_{x = 0}x_{0}x$$ but this series is divergent so this doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that the domain of $X$ is $S$. We know that 
$$
E(X)=\sum_{s\in S}sP(X=s)
$$
(the sum may be replaced by an integral).
We must have $x_0\in S$. For any other $s\in S$, we have $P(s)=0$, thus, all terms except for $x_0P(X=x_0)$ vanish, yielding:
$$
E(X)=x_0P(X=x_0)=x_0
$$
since $P(X=x_0)=1$.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a constant random variable $X$ with cumulative density function defined by:

$$F_{X}(x)=\begin{cases}1 & x\geq x_{0} \\ 0 & x< x_{0}\end{cases}$$

We want to find the expectation of $X$:

$$\operatorname{E}[X]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf_{X}(x)\:\mathrm{d}x=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x\delta(x-x_{0})\:\mathrm{d}x=x_{0}$$

Where $\delta(\cdot)$ is the [Dirac delta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function), defined by:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(x)\:\mathrm{d}x=1 \text{ and } \delta(x)=\begin{cases}\infty & x=0 \\ 0 & x \neq 0\end{cases}$$